# What is equivalent of value_of_css_property in Scrapy using Selector?

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy, selector

for getting background from this tag

```
<body style="background-image: url(&quot;http://www.auchandrive.fr/drive/static-media/public2/zones_edit/bannieres/_2016/S49/background_festif2016_boutique.jpg&quot;)
```

I use this code in **Selenium**

```
background = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body').value_of_css_property('background-image')
```

how can i use this in Scrapy using Css Selector or Xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scrapy you can use [CSS selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#selectors) directly:

You can get the node attribute with:

```
style = response.css('body::attr(style)').extract_first()
```

After this I am afraid scrapy doesn't offer something like `value_of_css_property` directly, so you'll have to parse the attribute yourself:

```
value = response.css("body::attr(style)").re_first('background-image: (.*)$')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i updated my question, your code return "None", but  when i use selenium i have the value